# Convert angular2 component name / "this" to String

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular2 Component, when doing:

```
console.log (this);
```

you get as expected the whole object with all members, e.g.

```
"ComponentName {member1, member2, member_n}"
```

Now I want to only log the ComponentName. How to achieve?

Comment: what is ComponentName? have you tried `this.ComponentName` ?

Comment: Here, `ComponentName` is the name of the component, e.g. in Angular 2 we do: `export class MySuperCoolComponent { .. }`

Comment: nice question but strange one...

Comment: In complex software projects, when you want to do modular logging (maybe even into some REST service), you won't find the question strange anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Really interesting question, this is what you are looking for:

```
console.log(this.constructor.name);
```

Comment: Great reply, thanks! Confirmed Working on all my Services and Components.

Comment: @Stefan very nice answer,

Comment: This works. However, be aware that angular-cli/webpack and other name-shortening JavaScript minify tools may change your class name to a single letter. So in dev mode it'll be "MyClass" but after minification just a single letter "a". This can be annoying if you need to look at production console logs or break your code if you use this.constructor.name for logic.